# Why has my appetite decreased so much since working out more frequently?

Tags: exercise, diet, gym

I've looked around elsewhere on the site, and other articles online, but I cannot seem to find anything to confirm either way.

I've always been a sporty person, playing different sports regularly as well as watching them. As recently as a year ago, I was able to eat large meals, the sorts of ones that come on a plate big enough to stretch 2 seats at a restaurant table, and that you get for free if you get through the full thing. I was working out a few times a week, playing football, running etc and staying slim.

However, I now struggle to eat large quantities and even some just above average sized meals now, and the only real change is that I play less football, but workout and run more regularly and more intensely.

Does this have something to do with the loss of appetite or why I feel full a lot faster than before?

Even my other half has noticed a difference from when I've taken her out for dinner.

I love eating and working out, so this is a bit of rock and a hard place for me!

Comment: Related: [Exercise & Loss of Appetite](http://www.livestrong.com/article/405012-exercise-loss-of-appetite/)

Comment: @CCCV I'm certainly not over training, generally I only get time to train for 30-60 minutes a night, and my sleeping pattern is 11:30-7:30 most nights

Comment: Per [How Exercise Can Help Us Eat Less](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/09/11/how-exercise-can-help-us-eat-less/), "_Strenuous_ exercise seems to _dull the urge to eat afterward_ better than gentler workouts...." (emphasis mine).  You say that you train in the evening, and you mention eating less when you eat dinner away from home; if you train "intensely"/strenuously before you eat, then your appetite may decrease per the article's discussion.

Comment: @CCCV yeah, I train in the evening, however on the days I go out to eat I don't train at all, since I have to travel from my town to the city where my partner lives and leave early in the morning

Comment: I have no further ideas for you at the moment.  Best wishes!

Comment: Has your diet changed in any way?  Perhaps you were eating a lot of carbs which are quite easy to pack down, but now you eat more protein and fat, causing you to be full?  Also, did you stop playing sports around the same time you noticed your appetite decrease?

Comment: @Craig Not that I'm aware of, I'm still eating the same foods, and have a relatively balanced diet, I think probably the diet decreasing happened a little before, but it's been a while now so it's hard to really know for sure

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at this slideshow.  It includes some good possible reasons such as hormones (particularly testosterone as we age), stress, and sleep.  I can say from personal experience that #6 is probably false (I'm eating about 70% of my calories from fat, 25% from protein, and the rest vegetables... and I do not at all agree)  [slideshow](http://www.everydayhealth.com/weight-pictures/triggers-that-will-slow-your-metabolism.aspx#01)

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but for a comment anyway: I have encountered similar reactions of my body. Especially after running I've had days when I (figuratively) could not eat anything.

Comment: Also not enough for an answer: It's clear you can't eat (a lot) before a workout (otherwise you'll puke). I suspect after a workout the body tries to stay ready for another one (say, maybe you were running away from a lion and need to stay ready in case it catches up again :) ) and so doesn't want you to eat too much right away. That matches my experiences, can't eat before a work out and after a workout I'll need some time before I grow hungry (unless I have a really big energy deficit, and even then often I'm more tired than hungry).

Answer (score 2):

> **Intense Exercises Influence on Appetite Regulating Hormones.**
>   *(especially aerobic)*

The following hormones play a role in appetite regulation. These hormonal effects can be seen after acute exercise and are also associated with long-term appetite changes.

---

### Hormone Release: *Increases*

**GLP-1:** Delays the speed of digesting food (kind of like fiber reduces sugar spikes). GLP-1 reduces the speed of glucose intake.

**PYY:** 
A hormone released after eating, it inhibits gastric motility and increases water and electrolyte absorption in the colon. When released it reduces appetite.

**Pancreatic Polypeptide (PP)**: Is a gut hormone released in response to ingestion of food. Plasma PP has been associated with decreased appetite and food intake.

---

### Hormone Release: *Decreases*

**Ghrelin:** is a fast-acting hormone, when released it play major role in meal initiation.

---

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24174308
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17212793
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12915697

Answer (score 0):

Getting stressed may affect your diet. It also depends on the type of diet . If you are eating a highly protein rich diet then you may not feel that hungry. Perhaps you are not enjoying your food. Try new dishes new cuisine. However try to avoid stress and enjoy life. Remember the good memories you've had in your past while you eat or watch tv. You will be shocked by your Real appetite.  Engage your partner in an interesting conversation about her interests you will not only enjoy your meal but also develop better bonding with her. Try to forget work while eating.  This is bound to help. Else consult your doctor. Check ypur weight. Maybe you wrte just overloading ypur stomach earlier. With age that is as you near 45 your metabolism tends to slow down. I am sure you will be able to get over this problem.

Comment: Hmmm... I generally don't get too stressed, although admittedly I was for a week, but even before then my diet had decreased. The food I'm eating is certainly food that I enjoy (probably the most frustrating part!). I guess the most likely explanation is that, although I was never fat or even close to being, there was more fat on my body than there is now, and so there was the potential for me to be able to eat more.

Comment: Some references to support your answer would be useful